# Counting duplicates in a vector of cv::Points2f

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, stdmap

Im Trying to find and count the duplicated cv::Points2f in a vector. For this purpose I tried to use the following function. But Im getting an error when I try to use the dereferenced value `rv[*val]++`.

```
std::map<cv::Point2f, unsigned int> counter(const std::vector<Point2f>& vals) 
{    
    std::map<Point2f, unsigned int> rv;

    for (auto val = vals.begin(); val != vals.end(); ++val) {
        rv[*val]++;

    }

    return rv;
}
```

At the end I want to habe a container with the list of keys (without the duplicated ones) and how many times was found each of them in the original vector.

e.g. for the following vector

```
vector<Point2f> v{Point2f(2,2),Point2f(3,3),Point2f(1,2),Point2f(2,2),Point2f(3,3)};
```

I want to get a container with this information:
(1,2) 1;
(2,2) 2;
(3,3) 2

**EDIT:**

just to clarify i get diverse notes and errors as:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:387:20: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const cv::Point_<float>’ and ‘const cv::Point_<float>’)
       { return __x < __y; }

/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:1031:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const cv::Point_<float>’ to ‘const cv::String&’
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What's "*an error*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are missing the comparison operator for the Point class, so you need to provide it, for example:

```
bool operator <(const cv::Point2f &a, const cv::Point2f &b)
{
    if (a.x < b.x) return true;
    if (a.x > b.x) return false;
    return a.y < b.y;
}
```

The second note is saying that there is an operator < available for cv:::String, but the Point2f is not convertible to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im really new re-defining operators. When I just copy this operator implementation before my function and compile my code again, Im getting the same error. May Im forgetting something or doing something wrong?

Comment: I realized that I had to add `namespace cv {... your code}` in order to make it works. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a specific type as a key in a `std::map` (`Point2f` in this) case then you have to define `operator<` for your type, since a map sorts it's elments using `operator<`, how otherwise will it know what element is smaller than the other?